# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&' (dynamic import)

Tags: javascript, webpack

[image]

I've started to see this issue after I implemented chunks with dynamic import, I've found some solutions for this case :

1. add `<base />`
2. add `publicPath: '/'` to webpack config

these solutions described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2882), but it doesn't work. If there some other ways to fix it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script defer type="text/javascript">
      {`(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
             new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
             j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-SOME_GMT_CODE');`}
    </script>
```

issue was in this code snipped , not in main bundle